# Django-paypal invoice has already been paid

Tags: python, django, paypal, django-paypal

I'm using [django-shop-paypal](https://github.com/chrisglass/django-shop-paypal) and when i want to checkout via paypal I get a message "invoice has already been paid".
The plugin posts the order ID as unique-invoice-id like 17 or 18.

When I manually change the unique-invoice-id to something like 189674 in the form and post to Paypal the checkout will work correctly.

Does anyone know why a simple small unique number does not work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be because you have already got paid invoices with the same number (maybe with a different site or previous tests)

Either prefix the invoices numbers with a unique code or number to make the invoice number different, or log into paypal and allow duplicate invoice numbers to be paid.

> My Account > Profile > Selling Preferences
>
> Block payments  Limit payments, add instructions and more. Click
>   Update
>
> Block accidental payments: You may prevent accidental payments by
>   blocking duplicate invoice IDs No, allow multiple payments per invoice
>   ID